# Don´t know how to convert a String into a byte array

Tags: java

I have the next assignment, I need to create a code that writes de characters of a String object to a byte array.

First of all I have to ask the user for a String, then I have to create te byte array, the first  position of this array must contain a counter.

The array contains the ASCII code of each character of the String, and the counter contains the length of the String,I have to use the String.getBytes() method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ByteArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int l;
        String string;
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("String: ");
        string= read.nextLine();
        l = string.length()+1;
        byte arrayBytes[] = new byte[l];
        arrayBytes = string.getBytes();
        arrayBytes[0] = l;
    }
}
```

the problem is that I don´t know if I am using correctly the getBytes() method to convert a String to a bytearray, and at the same time to put in the first position the number of characters of the array

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: Here's the real trouble:  if you enter in a multi-digit number, you won't have the numeral you care about at index 0.  Otherwise your approach looks fine (you do declare an unnecessary variable `l` which can just go away IMO).

Comment: I think you'll need `System.arraycopy` somewhere along the way.

Comment: @DavidWallace - or a loop.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that I don´t know if I am using correctly the getBytes() method to convert a String to a bytearray, and at the same time to put in the first position the number of characters of the array

No you aren't.

If you read the javadoc for `String.getBytes()` it tells you that it returns a newly allocated byte array that contains the string in a byte-encoded representation.  The first byte of the encoded String will be in offset zero of the array.  That is NOT what you need for your (ultimate) result.

Furthermore, what you have written is going to create a 1 byte array, and then discard it.

This problem requires you to allocate a second array (of the right size), and then transfer bytes from the first one to the second one in the right place.  There are at least a couple of ways to do that.  (Hint: one involves coding a loop.)

There is another detail that you have missed.  The problem specifically requires you to put the ASCII codes of characters into the array, but getBytes() doesn't necessarily encode the characters as ASCII.  (Look at the javadocs again.  The answer is there.)